# Assign value in column by group R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
          id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4),
      rating = c("No rating", "Red", "No rating", "Red", "Green", "Red",
                 "No rating", "Green"),
         pct = c(10.34079909, 89.65920091, 91.28335721, 8.71664279, 21, 83, 2,
                 10)
```

I am trying to create a new variable, called `flag`, to determine when a group, `id` meets a certain condition. For example:

```
data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(flag = case_when(
    pct > .05 & rating == "Red" ~ TRUE,
    TRUE ~ FALSE))
```

Once the flag condition is met, I want all values in `flag` to be `TRUE` for that specific `id`, not only for the rows where that condition is met.

Comment: You can just do `data %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(flag = any(rating == "Red" & pct > 0.05))`.

Comment: I tried this too, but this produces a result where the flag variable is TRUE and FALSE depending on if the row fulfills the condition (e.g., an id has two different ratings or pcts). I want the condition to be TRUE for *all* rows of an id if any single row fulfills the condition.

Comment: It is doing exactly that.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not to familiar with dplyr, but this does work if I understand the question correctly

```
data <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4), rating = c("No rating", "Red", "No rating", "Red", "Green", "Red", "No rating", "Green"), pct = c(10.34079909, 89.65920091, 91.28335721, 8.71664279, 21, 83, 2, 10))

data$bin <- ifelse(data$pct > .05 & data$rating == "Red", TRUE, FALSE)
df       <- merge(data, aggregate(data=data, bin~id, max), by.x="id", by.y = "id")

head(df)

id    rating       pct bin.x bin.y
1  1 No rating 10.340799 FALSE     1
2  1       Red 89.659201  TRUE     1
3  2 No rating 91.283357 FALSE     1
4  2       Red  8.716643  TRUE     1
5  3     Green 21.000000 FALSE     1
6  3       Red 83.000000  TRUE     1
```